# Laravel Eloquent: how to display all rows if search text field is empty

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, http-status-code-404, is-empty

First a demonstration if there is a value:

**Text Field:**

```
<input type="text" id="search_category" class="search_category" placeholder="Search by Category" value="a">
```

**Ajax function:** (to show the data from the textfield being taken)

```
var search_category = $('#search_category').val();
------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data/"+search_category,
```

**SQL Select:**

```
public function fetchcategory($search_category){
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::query()
                                    ->when(empty($search_category), function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('category_id', '>=', '1');
                                    })
                                    //iLike is case insensitive
                                    ->when(!empty($search_category), function ($query) use ($search_category) {
                                        $query->where('category_name', 'iLIKE', "%$search_category%");
                                    })    
                                      ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                      ->get(); }
```

since my textfield has `value="a"`, the query triggers `!empty()`, showing:

[image: 1]

my problem is that if I change the textfield to `value=""` which is blank and to trigger `when(empty())`, the rows do not show and I get the error

```
404 not found
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
```

how do i stop this error from happening if my text field is empty?

Summary: trying to output all rows if search value is empty, 404 error right now

Update: tried this, I still cannot search if text field is blank

```
    url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data/?search="+search_category,
    Route::get('/bbr-category-configuration-data/?search={search_category}', [BBRCategoryConfigurationController::class,'fetchcategory']);

    $search_category = request('search');
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::query()
                                    ->when(empty($search_category), function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('category_id', '>=', 1);
                                    })
                                    //iLike is case insensitive
                                    ->when(!empty($search_category), function ($query) use ($search_category) {
                                        $query->where('category_name', 'iLIKE', "%$search_category%");
                                    })    
                                      ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')
                                      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes around 1. It's now being considered as a String, not Integer. The line should be:

```
$query->where('category_id', '>=', 1);
```

**UPDATE**

You should also update your route like:

```
 Route::get('/bbr-category-configuration-data', [BBRCategoryConfigurationController::class,'fetchcategory']);
```

Ajax Function :

```
var search_value = $('#search_category').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data:{search_categoy:search_value},
    url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data/",
```

And in your method:

```
$search_category = request('search_category');
```

You are getting a 404 because of the way you have declared your route. As you have declared 'search_category' as your route parameter, you will always have to pass a value for it. Therefore, it works when a value is passed for the parameter. But when the the parameter remains empty, it throws a '404 Not found' error. Because Laravel is expecting a value for search_category parameter but couldn't find one.

Comment: issue is still the same, but this is probably another fix. its likely that this error will show up when my main concern is solved.

Comment: the problem is with your route config. I just noticed. If you declare your route like that, you will always have to pass a value for search_category. A better solution is just to declare the url without the query parameter in your router. You will not get 404 anymore after that.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the problem and shared code to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your logic and not chain `when` methods, something like this:

```php
public function fetchcategory($search_category){
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::query();
    if (empty($search_category)) {
        $all_categories->where("category_id", ">=", 1);
    } else {
        $all_categories->where("category_name", "iLIKE", "%$search_category%");
    }

    return $all_categories->orderBy("category_id"; "ASC")->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 404 occurs probably because you don't have registered correct route `/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data`. Instead of passing search_category as url route try to pass it as query string like this.

```
/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data/?search=" + search_category
```

Then you may get this value by request helper inside your controller

```
$search_category = request('search');
```

Make sure you have correct route register in web.php or api.php file.

Comment: tried this, it still cant search when blank (tried with and without brackets in route)